# heroku installing python 3.6.2 instead of python 2.7

Tags: python, heroku, deployment

I have written a python 2.7 based flask app, however when I push it to heroku using `git push heroku master` i see in termonal that it installs python version 3.6.2 instead of python version 2.7.

how should I fix this and why is it picking python 3.6 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newly created Python applications in heroku will be default to the Python 3.6.2 ..
so if you want to specify a version of Python to be used to run your application.

This functionality is enabled by the presence of a runtime.txt file.

```
mohi@dev:~$ vi runtime.txt
mohi@dev:~$ cat runtime.txt
python-2.7.13
```

If you specify a different Python runtime than a previous build, your application’s build cache will be purged.

Comment: still its installing python 3.6

`remote: -----> Python app detected`
`remote: -----> Found python-3.6.2, removing`

Comment: did you added runtime.txt in your project directory?

Comment: offcourse, where route module that initialzes the app.

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz, the `runtime.txt` file must be in the root of your repository.